# RxJava2 on MVP. an when to use it

Tags: java, android, mvp, rx-java2

I'm just learning RxJava on android and I'm implementing MVP pattern on my app. I'm using RxJava on my rest API from model and model to a presenter, From presenter, I'm wondering if I should also implement RxJava from presenter to view(Activity/fragments)? Or should I prefer normal interface methods? Also is there a guideline as to when to use RxJava and when not to. Also if it is good to implement RxJava in view, is there a way to make three completable namely: `onSuccess()`,`onFailure(String message)` and `onError(String message)` replaced by a single Observable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, and there are lots of articles about architecture and reactive programming. So I would start from reading and playing with samples, and then asking concrete questions.

Worth mentioning that reactive approach works better with `MVVM` rather that with `MVP`. Also recent Google Architecture Components are about `MVVM`.

Some useful articles:

- [Reactive Clean Architecture with Android Architecture Components](https://mag.n26.com/reactive-clean-architecture-with-android-architecture-components-685a6682e0ca)
- [Practical example using Reactive Clean Architecture approach](https://mag.n26.com/practical-example-using-reactive-clean-architecture-approach-8a2436ea76b4)
- [Save your backend from a responsive UI using RxJava](https://medium.com/@belchii/save-your-backend-from-a-responsive-ui-using-rxjava-929dbcc33c3a)
- [Android Architecture Components — now with 100% more MVVM](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-now-with-100-more-mvvm-11629a630125)

And useful to know how Android apps architecture evolved:

1. [MVC](https://upday.github.io/blog/model-view-controller/)
2. [MVP](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-2-model-view-presenter-8a6faaae14a5)
3. [MVVM](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b)

Comment: sorry about it being too broad. But what I'm trying to say is, for example I have a log in activity after authenticating, is it preferable to update my activity lets say start another activity via simple interface method like void onSuccess() or in a reactive way?

Comment: Again, your question is way too broad. There are a lot of design and architectural constraints that go into making that decision.